# Generating stanford semantic graph with nodes storing lemma

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to generate a SemanticGraph and use semgrex to find the specific node.
I would like to use lemma as one of node attribute in semgrex. I saw a relevant question and answer here:

[CoreNLP SemanticGraph - search for edges with specific lemmas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326451/corenlp-semanticgraph-search-for-edges-with-specific-lemmas)

It is mentioned that

> Make sure that the nodes are storing lemmas -- see the lemma annotator of CoreNLP (currently available for English, only).

I current can use pipeline to generate the desired annotation to generate the semantic graph.

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse");
 StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

However, after searching for relevant information, I only find a deprecated function at here:

https://github.com/chbrown/nlp/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/ParserAnnotatorUtils.java

```
public static SemanticGraph generateDependencies(Tree tree,
    boolean collapse,
    boolean ccProcess,
    boolean includeExtras,
    boolean lemmatize,
    boolean threadSafe) {
  SemanticGraph deps = SemanticGraphFactory.makeFromTree(tree, collapse, ccProcess, includeExtras, lemmatize, threadSafe);
  return deps;
}
```

which seemed to be removed from newest coreNLP.

Could anyone give some hint on how to generate the semantic graph with nodes that storing the lemmas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function as you have it should work. The lemmas will be stored in the `SemanticGraph` produced by the `parse` annotator. You can retrieve the graph after running your text through `pipeline.annotate(Annotation)` with:

`sentence.get(SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.BasicDependenciesAnnotation.class)`

Or, the equivalent for Collapsed and CollapsedCCProcessed dependencies. See http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.html. Note that these are attached to a sentence (CoreMap), not a document (Annotation).

You can then run Semgrex over the graph as usual; e.g., `{lemma:/foo/} >arctype {lemma:/bar/}`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It works. May I ask a follow up question? I tried to use stanford dependencies instead of universal dependencies by `props.put("parse.originalDependencies", true);`. However, it still give me universal dependencies as output. Anything that I am missing?