# create a semantic graph from a document in python?

Tags: python, graph, nlp, semantics

I am new to Python. I wanted to how to create a semantic graph from a document say a news article. The Stanford corenlp does ([Generating stanford semantic graph with nodes storing lemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31177593/generating-stanford-semantic-graph-with-nodes-storing-lemma)) have an option, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Stanford's tool is in java. For python I suggest you the [Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spaCy](http://spacy.io/) that supports syntactic dependencies.